# How to select rows displaying number of days since last moment of occurrence of specific predicate?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table with data that look like this:

```
KEYWORD, CONVERSIONS, CREATED_AT
'Travel agent', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Travel agent', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Travel agent', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Travel agent', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Travel agent', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Travel agent', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Travel agent', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Travel agent', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Travel agent', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Travel agency vizier', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Travel agency vizier', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Travel agency vizier', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Travel agency vizier', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Travel agency vizier', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Travel agency vizier', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Travel agency vizier', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Travel agency vizier', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Travel agency vizier', 1, '2015-04-09'
'Coral', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Coral', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Coral', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Coral', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Coral', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Coral', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Coral', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Coral', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Coral', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Coral travel', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Coral travel', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Coral travel', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Coral travel', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Coral travel', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Coral travel', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Coral travel', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Coral travel', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Coral travel', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Egypt last minute', 1, '2015-04-01'
'Egypt last minute', 1, '2015-04-02'
'Egypt last minute', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Egypt last minute', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Egypt last minute', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Egypt last minute', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Egypt last minute', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Egypt last minute', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Egypt last minute', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Egypt holidays', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Egypt holidays', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Egypt holidays', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Egypt holidays', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Egypt holidays', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Egypt holidays', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Egypt holidays', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Egypt holidays', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Egypt holidays', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Exim', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Exim', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Exim', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Exim', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Exim', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Exim', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Exim', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Exim', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Exim', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Greece last minute', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Greece last minute', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Greece last minute', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Greece last minute', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Greece last minute', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Greece last minute', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Greece last minute', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Greece holidays', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Greece holidays', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Greece holidays', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Greece holidays', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Greece holidays', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Greece holidays', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Greece holidays', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Greece holidays', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Greece holidays', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Last-minute', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Last-minute', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Last-minute', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Last-minute', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Last-minute', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Last-minute', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Last-minute', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Last-minute', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Last-minute', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Last Minute', 1, '2015-04-01'
'Last Minute', 1, '2015-04-02'
'Last Minute', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Last Minute', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Last Minute', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Last Minute', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Last Minute', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Last Minute', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Last Minute', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Last Minute Egypt', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Last Minute Egypt', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Last Minute Egypt', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Last Minute Egypt', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Last Minute Egypt', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Last Minute Egypt', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Last Minute Egypt', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Last Minute Egypt', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Last Minute Egypt', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Last minute holidays', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Last minute holidays', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Last minute holidays', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Last minute holidays', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Last minute holidays', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Last minute holidays', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Last minute holidays', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Last minute holidays', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Last minute holidays', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Offer holiday', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Offer holiday', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Offer holiday', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Offer holiday', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Offer holiday', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Offer holiday', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Offer holiday', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Offer holiday', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Offer holiday', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Sun & fun', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Sun & fun', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Sun & fun', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Sun & fun', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Sun & fun', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Sun & fun', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Sun & fun', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Sun & fun', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Sun & fun', 2, '2015-04-09'
'Sun and fun', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Sun and fun', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Sun and fun', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Sun and fun', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Sun and fun', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Sun and fun', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Sun and fun', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Sun and fun', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Sun and fun', 1, '2015-04-09'
'Lodge', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Lodge', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Lodge', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Lodge', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Lodge', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Lodge', 1, '2015-04-06'
'Lodge', 1, '2015-04-07'
'Lodge', 1, '2015-04-08'
'Lodge', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Holiday', 4, '2015-04-01'
'Holiday', 4, '2015-04-02'
'Holiday', 1, '2015-04-03'
'Holiday', 1, '2015-04-04'
'Holiday', 1, '2015-04-05'
'Holiday', 3, '2015-04-06'
'Holiday', 3, '2015-04-07'
'Holiday', 3, '2015-04-08'
'Holiday', 3, '2015-04-09'
'Wakacje.pl', 13, '2015-04-01'
'Wakacje.pl', 13, '2015-04-02'
'Wakacje.pl', 1, '2015-04-03'
'Wakacje.pl', 1, '2015-04-04'
'Wakacje.pl', 1, '2015-04-05'
'Wakacje.pl', 6, '2015-04-06'
'Wakacje.pl', 6, '2015-04-07'
'Wakacje.pl', 6, '2015-04-08'
'Wakacje.pl', 4, '2015-04-09'
'Holiday 2014', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Holiday 2014', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Holiday greece', 1, '2015-04-01'
'Holiday greece', 1, '2015-04-02'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Last-minute holiday', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Last-minute holiday', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Last-minute holiday', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Last-minute holiday', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Last-minute holiday', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Last-minute holiday', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Last-minute holiday', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Last-minute holiday', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Last-minute holiday', 1, '2015-04-09'
'Holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Vacation en', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Vacation en', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Vacation en', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Vacation en', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Vacation en', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Vacation en', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Vacation en', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Vacation en', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Vacation en', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Holiday in Greece', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Holiday in Greece', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Holiday in Greece', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Holiday in Greece', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Holiday in Greece', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Holiday in Greece', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Holiday in Greece', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Holiday in Greece', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Holiday in Greece', 1, '2015-04-09'
'Holidays abroad', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Holidays abroad', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Holidays abroad', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Holidays abroad', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Holidays abroad', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Holidays abroad', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Holidays abroad', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Holidays abroad', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Holidays abroad', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Holiday', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Holiday', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Holiday', 1, '2015-04-03'
'Holiday', 1, '2015-04-04'
'Holiday', 1, '2015-04-05'
'Holiday', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Holiday', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Holiday', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Holiday', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Egypt holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Egypt holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Egypt holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Egypt holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Egypt holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Egypt holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Egypt holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Egypt holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Egypt holiday last minute', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Holiday greece', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Travel abroad', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Travel abroad', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Travel abroad', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Travel abroad', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Travel abroad', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Travel abroad', 1, '2015-04-06'
'Travel abroad', 1, '2015-04-07'
'Travel abroad', 1, '2015-04-08'
'Travel abroad', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Vizier holidays', 1, '2015-04-01'
'Vizier holidays', 1, '2015-04-02'
'Vizier holidays', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Vizier holidays', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Vizier holidays', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Vizier holidays', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Vizier holidays', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Vizier holidays', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Vizier holidays', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Www vacation en ', 0,' 2015-04-01 '
'Www vacation en ', 0,' 2015-04-02 '
'Www vacation en ', 0,' 2015-04-03 '
'Www vacation en ', 0,' 2015-04-04 '
'Www vacation en ', 0,' 2015-04-05 '
'Www vacation en ', 0,' 2015-04-06 '
'Www vacation en ', 0,' 2015-04-07 '
'Www vacation en ', 0,' 2015-04-08 '
'Www vacation en ', 1,' 2015-04-09 '
'Trips', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Trips', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Trips', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Trips', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Trips', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Trips', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Trips', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Trips', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Trips', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Tours', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Tours', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Tours', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Tours', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Tours', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Tours', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Tours', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Tours', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Tours', 0, '2015-04-09'
'Trips abroad', 0, '2015-04-01'
'Trips abroad', 0, '2015-04-02'
'Trips abroad', 0, '2015-04-03'
'Trips abroad', 0, '2015-04-04'
'Trips abroad', 0, '2015-04-05'
'Trips abroad', 0, '2015-04-06'
'Trips abroad', 0, '2015-04-07'
'Trips abroad', 0, '2015-04-08'
'Trips abroad', 0, '2015-04-09'
```

It is a part of the Google Analytics API report.
`KEYWORD` column contains keywords used to advertise site,
`CONVERSIONS` column has number of conversions at day named in `CREATED_AT`.

The specific predicate is `date range`:
`WHERE '2015-04-01' <= created_at AND created_at <= '2015-04-09'`

The query I try to write should print the amount of days since last conversion and date of last conversion (or null/'never' if there was no conversion in `date range`). So results I'm looking for look like this for `today` (CURRENT_DATE = '2015-04-10'):

```
KEYWORD, DAYS_SINCE_CONVERSION, LAST_CONVERSION_DATE
'Travel agent', null, null
'Travel agency vizier', 1, '2015-04-09'
'Egypt last minute', 8, '2015-04-02'
'Exim', null, null
'Last Minute', 8, '2015-04-02'
'Sun & fun', 1, '2015-04-09'
... (and so on - I gave here few keywords just for example)
```

I tried some SQLs but without any luck, I don't have anything to share here because I wasn't even close to desired result. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach to this (probably database-independent, but don't take my word on it):

```
select c.keyword, t.days_since, t.last_date from conversation c
left join (
  select keyword, current_date - max(created_at) as days_since, max(created_at) as last_date
  from conversation
  where created_at between '2015-04-01' and '2015-04-09'
  and conversations > 0
  group by keyword
) t on t.keyword = c.keyword
group c.keyword, t.days_since, t.last_date
```

Comment: Please be aware that this may not be the best solution performace-wise.

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question with `postgresql-9.4` so you can use a filtered aggregate for this:

```
select keyword, 
       max(created_at) filter (WHERE conversions > 0 AND created_at between '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-09') as last_conversion_date
from conversion
group by keyword;
```

This will return one row for each keyword and the latest `created_at` date in the given time range but only if there was a conversion (that is necessary to filter out, e.g. `'Travel agent', 0, '2015-04-09'`

To calculate the number of days since then, simply subtract that latest date from `current_date`. In order to not repeat the expression it's easier to put the query into a derived table for this:

```
select keyword, 
       current_date - last_conversion_date as days_since_conversion, 
       last_conversion_date
from (
  select keyword, 
         max(created_at) filter (WHERE conversions > 0 AND created_at between '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-09') as last_conversion_date
  from conversion
  group by keyword
) t
order by keyword;
```

`date '2015-04-01'` is the SQL standard's syntax for writing a date literal I prefer it over the implicit date style where only a string is used.

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d9aff/1

The SQLFiddle uses a `case when` expression instead of the `filter` expression because `filter` isn't available in earlier Postgres versions.